# Como recorrer un json con ionic 3

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic3

Estoy trabajando con ionic3 y angular4, estoy recorriendo un json desde una rest api (por medio de la url) sin problema alguno, pero solo quiero acceder a un dato en especifico de este json. Por ejemplo, solo a la posición "1".

Home.ts :

[image: Home.ts]

Para recorrerlo:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts; ">

  <h1>{{post.enunciado_pregunta}}</h1>
  <br>

</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si tienes control de la api deberías hacer algo como esto:
http://midominio/api/momentos/pregunta/id
así solo recuperaras solo lo que necesita no debes consultar todos los registros, o no entiendo bien tu pregunta, podrías aclararla

Comment: Daniel, por ejemplo en este caso el JSON tiene 15 objetos dentro (15 preguntas con sus respectivas respuestas) y actualmente con el ngFor que puse mas arriba siempre me muestra los 15 al mostrarlo así {{post.enunciado_pregunta}}, cuando en verdad lo que deseo hacer es que en distintas paginas html solo se muestre una de las preguntas a la vez. Entonces lo que necesito es saber como hacer que solo se muestre la pregunta que yo deseo, osea la pregunta de x ubicación del JSON y sus respectivos datos.

Comment: Hola que pena la demora ya resolviste tu inconveniente?

Comment: Bueno pues una solución seria armar urls http:localhost:4200/pregunta/:id
el cual el id sería el index de tu lista de preguntas asi no la tienes que recorrer con el *ngFor si no leer directamente el index de tu array, no se si me hago entender.

Answer (score 0):

**¿Que tal compañero?**

Para poder resolver tu inconveniente, tienes que hacer un `console.log` a tu `response` y observar si ya tienes la data en dicha **variable**.

Una vez te hayas fijado que todo va de forma correcta, tienes que colocar los valores en un `array` y la variable `posts` no esta inicializado como un **array**. Entonces lo que se tiene que hacer es colocarlo de la siguiente forma:

> posts: any[ ] = [ ];

De esta forma ya podras hacerle un **for** a tu lista. También indicarte que sería mejor utilizar `<ion-list></ion-list>` para iterar tus `ion-item`

Espero te ayude y me comentas si lo resolviste.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo intenté obtener el objeto JSON con esa función, pero me fallaba, lo que hice fue transformar la promesa en objeto JSON con otras funciones, de esta manera:

Declaro una variable cuentas: `any[]` en la clase:

```
getDato(){
  let url = 'http://alguna url';
  return this.http.get(url).toPromise(); //para volverlo promesa 
}
```

En donde lo vayas a usar, hacer esto:

```
this.getDato()
    .then(
      (data) => {
        //Obtengo una promesa
        this.infocuentas = (data['cuenta'])

        //Convierto esa promesa a una cadena de cuentas
        this.infocuentas = JSON.stringify(this.infocuentas)

        //A partir de la cadena, creo objeto JSON Cuenta
        this.cuentas = JSON.parse(this.infocuentas); 

        //recorres este vector como cualquier JSON sin problema
      },
      (error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
```